# Move the same unique_ptr into function in a loop

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

Whats the best way to redesign the following error prone code:

```
void ClassA::methodA(std::unique_ptr<ClassB::ISomeInterface> obj){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      methodB(std::move(obj)); // the obj pointer is undefined on second iteration here after the move
    }
  }

void ClassA::methodB(std::unique_ptr<ClassB::ISomeInterface> obj){
      ..........
}
```

The goal is to pass the same unique_ptr to function  multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to transfer ownership just pass the raw pointer or a reference. If the functions are going to store the pointer a `shared_ptr` would be more appropriate:

```
void ClassA::methodA(std::unique_ptr<ClassB::ISomeInterface> obj){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      methodB(*obj);
    }
  }

void ClassA::methodB(ClassB::ISomeInterface& obj){
      ..........
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass it by (optionally `const`) reference to methodB.

So instead of having

```
void ClassA::methodB(std::unique_ptr<ClassB::ISomeInterface> obj);
```

you can have either of the following

```
void ClassA::methodB(const ClassB::ISomeInterface& obj);
```

or

```
void ClassA::methodB(ClassB::ISomeInterface& obj);
```